# Editing 3rd party angular components

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I need to edit some components by Kendo.

Followed instructions here:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/installation/source-code/

Every time I try to import Module into my app.module component I get an error:

[Cannot find module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoOWa.png)

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated Getting Started tutorial uses Angular CLI and therefore WebPack 2. Check the following [documentation section](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/177)  for details.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to edit some component and include it in my project.